# Crashing before I can push into a queue

Tags: c++, queue

So I have this code and I'm trying to simulate multilevel feedback queues but before I can do that it wont let me run it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>  
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class processME{
public:
    int pid;
    int time;

};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    queue <processME, int> q1;
    queue <processME, int> q2;
    queue <processME, int> q3;
    processME stopWatch;
    int random = rand() % 17 + 1;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++){
        stopWatch.time;

        if (random<7){

            q1.push(2);
        }
        else if (random<12){
            q2.push(3);

        }
        else{
            q3.push(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run this it would give me a bunch of errors in the queue file
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: errors like what? Compile time errors? Garbage? Or crash? Need to specify a bit more.

Comment: error C2825: '_Container': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
these and plenty more

Comment: where is the constructor is the class processMe?

Comment: Read the documentation on queue's template parameters. `int` is not a container.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `std::queue` looks like:

```
template<class T, class Container = std::deque<T>> class queue;
```

The first parameter is the type to be stored in the `queue`. If you want to store more than one type, wrap it in a `tuple` or some user defined class.

The second parameter is the container type. The various requirements for the type can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), but it expects types like `list` or `deque`. Passing `int` to it will result in many error messages.